# Cannot reach keepalived VIP from other machines in the same network

Tags: centos, high-availability, keepalived, virtual-ip

I am working in bare metal environment trying to setup HA loadbalancing using keepalived. When I try to ping the VIP which I given in keepalived config file from other machines in the same network its not reachable, but when I stop keepalived in one of the machines, the other becomes master and IP address is assigned automatically.

`keepalived configuration`

```
vrrp_instance VI_PUB
{
        interface ens34
        state MASTER
        virtual_router_id 52
        priority 101
        virtual_ipaddress
        {
                192.167.3.54
        }
        track_interface
        {
                ens34
        }
}
virtual_server 192.167.3.54 8081
{
        delay_loop 4
        lb_algo sh # source hash
        lb_kind NAT
        protocol TCP
        real_server 172.16.3.23 8080
        {
                weight 1
                TCP_CHECK
                {
                        connect_timeout 15
                        nb_get_retry 3
                        delay_before_retry 2
                }
        }
        real_server 172.16.3.24 8080
        {
                weight 1
                TCP_CHECK
                {
                        connect_timeout 15
                        nb_get_retry 3
                        delay_before_retry 2
                }
        }
}
```

`ip addr show ens32` on current master

```
ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0c:29:43:c2:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.16.3.24/23 brd 172.16.3.255 scope global ens32
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.167.3.54/32 scope global ens32
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe43:c29c/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`route -n` on current master

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens32
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 ens32
172.16.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 ens32
```

`route -n` on one of the hosts in the current network

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens34
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 ens34
172.16.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 ens34
```

any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is your exact problem? The VIP is not reachable or VIP is not assigned to some node? VIP in your config is assigned as `/32` address. You need to setup proper routing to reach this IP.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actual problem is VIP is not reachable by other machines in the same network

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev yeah, i disabled the firewall

Answer (score 1):

I guess that

```
ip addr show | grep global
```

will show that your virtual address is

```
192.167.3.54/32
```

/32 is usually not the desired result, therefore you should add e.g. /24:

```
virtual_ipaddress {
  192.167.3.54/24
}
```